# How to update annotations when in mapview on zoom?

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation

I'm trying to make an app, where you get buses positions from web API. When I got the data, I put annotations on mapview for all of the coordinates i got from API. Then, when annotation is tapped on, I try to hide all the annotations which aren't on the same route as the one clicked. It works fine, but when I zoom out the annotations that weren't in the original region aren't hidden. Is there a way to refresh what is displayed when user zooms on map view?

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import MBProgressHUD
import Alamofire


class MapViewController: UIViewController {

//MARK: Properties and Outlets

private var timer: NSTimer?

private lazy var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

private var vehicles = [String: Vehicle]()

private var points = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()

private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

private var currentLocation: CLLocation?

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!


//MARK: Actions

@IBAction func getMyLocation(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    getLocation()
}

//MARK: Life Cycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(30, target: self, selector: "fetchVehiclesLocations", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    fetchVehiclesLocations()

    getLocation()
}

//MARK: Get Location

private func getLocation() {

    let authStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

    if authStatus == .NotDetermined {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        return
    }
    if authStatus == .Denied || authStatus == .Restricted {
        showLocationServicesDeniedAlert()
        return
    }

    startLocationManager()
}


//MARK: Helper methods

private func showLocationServicesDeniedAlert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Location Services Disabled", message: "Please enable location services for this app in Settings.", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(okAction)

    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

private func startLocationManager () {
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        showLoadingHUD()
    }
}

private func stopLocationManager() {
    locationManager.delegate = nil
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    hideLoadingHUD()
}




private func rotateBus() {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
        for (id, _) in self.vehicles {
            if self.vehicles[id]!.lastPosition != nil {
                let annotationView = self.mapView.viewForAnnotation(self.vehicles[id]!.annotation!)
                let currentLocationPoint = self.mapView.convertCoordinate(self.vehicles[id]!.lastPosition!, toPointToView: self.mapView)
                let destinationPoint = self.mapView.convertCoordinate(self.vehicles[id]!.coordinates, toPointToView: self.mapView)
                let yDiff = currentLocationPoint.y - destinationPoint.y
                let xDiff = destinationPoint.x - currentLocationPoint.x
                let arcTan = atan(yDiff / xDiff)
                var angle = CGFloat(M_PI / 2) - arcTan
                if xDiff < 0 {
                    angle = angle + CGFloat(M_PI)
                }
                if angle.isNaN || angle == 0.0 {
                    continue
                }
                else {
                    annotationView?.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(angle))
                }
            }
        }
        }, completion: nil)

    moveBus()
}

private func moveBus() {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(28.0, delay: 0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
        for(id, _) in self.vehicles {
            if self.vehicles[id]!.lastPosition != nil {
                self.vehicles[id]!.annotation?.coordinate = self.vehicles[id]!.coordinates
            }
        }
        }, completion: nil)
}


private func createVehicles() {
    print(vehicles.count)
    for (id, _) in vehicles {
        if vehicles[id]?.annotation == nil {
            let annotation = BusAnnotation()
            annotation.imageName = "bus"
            annotation.coordinate = vehicles[id]!.coordinates
            annotation.title = id
            vehicles[id]?.annotation = annotation
            mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }
    print(mapView.annotations.count)
    rotateBus()
}

private func drawPolyline() {
    let myPolyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &points, count: points.count)
    mapView.addOverlay(myPolyline)
}

//MARK: HUD display methods

private func showLoadingHUD() {
    let hud = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(mapView, animated: true)
    hud.labelText = "Getting Your Location..."
}

private func hideLoadingHUD() {
    MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(mapView, animated: true)
}

//MARK: Networking

func fetchVehiclesLocations() {
    let URL = urlVehiclesLocations + apiKey

    if !vehicles.isEmpty {
        for (id , _) in vehicles {
            vehicles[id]?.lastPosition = vehicles[id]?.coordinates
        }
    }

    Alamofire.request(.GET, URL)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON {
            (request, response, result) in

            guard result.isSuccess else {
                print("Error while fetching \(result.error!)")
                return
            }

            let value = result.value as? [String: AnyObject]
            let responseDict = value?["response"] as? [String: AnyObject]
            let array = responseDict?["entity"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]

            for var i = 0; i < array?.count; i++ {
                let item = array?[i]["vehicle"] as? [String: AnyObject]
                let position = item?["position"] as? [String: AnyObject]
                let trip = item?["trip"] as? [String: AnyObject]
                let vehicle = Vehicle()
                vehicle.latitude = position?["latitude"] as! Double
                vehicle.longitude = position?["longitude"] as! Double
                vehicle.tripId = trip?["trip_id"] as! String
                let startTime = trip?["start_time"] as! String
                vehicle.startTime = self.dateFormatter.dateFromString(startTime)
                let vehicleId = item?["vehicle"] as? [String: AnyObject]
                let id = vehicleId?["id"] as! String
                if self.vehicles[id] == nil {
                    self.vehicles[id] = vehicle
                }
                else {
                    self.vehicles[id]?.latitude = vehicle.latitude
                    self.vehicles[id]?.longitude = vehicle.longitude
                }
            }
            self.createVehicles()
    }
}

func fetchPointsForTripPolyline() {
    let URL = urlTripPolyline + apiKey

    Alamofire.request(.GET, URL)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON {
            (request, response, result) in

            guard result.isSuccess else {
                print("Error while fetching \(result.error!)")
                return
            }

            let value = result.value as! [String: AnyObject]
            let responseArray = value["response"] as! [[String: AnyObject]]
            for var i = 0; i < responseArray.count; i++ {
                let longitude = responseArray[i]["shape_pt_lon"] as! CLLocationDegrees
                let latitude = responseArray[i]["shape_pt_lat"] as! CLLocationDegrees
                let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
                self.points.append(coordinate)
            }

            self.drawPolyline()
    }
}
}
extension MapViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let newLocation = locations.last!

    if newLocation.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow < -5 {
        return
    }

    if newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0 {
        return
    }

    if newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= locationManager.desiredAccuracy {
        stopLocationManager()
        currentLocation = newLocation
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = newLocation.coordinate
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: newLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: newLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(center, 1000, 1000)

    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
}

extension MapViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    if !(annotation is BusAnnotation) {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = annotation.title!

    var busAnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId!)

    if busAnnotationView == nil {
        busAnnotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        busAnnotationView?.canShowCallout = true
    }
    else {
        busAnnotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }

    let busAnnotation = annotation as! BusAnnotation

    busAnnotationView?.image = UIImage(named: busAnnotation.imageName)

    return busAnnotationView
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    if overlay is MKPolyline {
        let lineView = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        lineView.lineWidth = 3.0
        lineView.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        return lineView
    }

    return MKOverlayRenderer()
}

func hideBuses(tripId: String) {
    for (_, vehicle) in vehicles {
        if vehicle.tripId != tripId {
            let annotationView = mapView.viewForAnnotation(vehicle.annotation!)
            annotationView?.hidden = true
        }
    }
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {
    let vehicleId = view.annotation?.title!
    let tripId = vehicles[vehicleId!]?.tripId
    hideBuses(tripId!)
}

}
```

Comment: You need to create an array (or perhaps since it seems you have a reference to the annotations on your `vehicles` object) of annotations for each seperate route. And then remove the one's that don't belong there. `MKMapView` is very different from other recycle type views from apple like `UITableView` instead of reloading like cells, `annotations` begin rendering as they are added to the mapView. The only way (that I've used, not saying it's impossible another way) to hide them is to remove them from the mapView.

Comment: Looking at your code it looks like you grab the polyline, which has an array of coordinates you do want. So you can just remove all your annotations after you get reference to the one's you need, And then just re-add the one's you need. To delete all annotations would look something like `mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)`

Comment: Thanks! I will try your solution!